# BLE scanning with Ionic4 on Android: not scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, ionic4

BLE scanning on Android does not work with Ionic4 (4.12.0) simple test app. There is no error message, enable checks are coming back positively. The subscription just never returns. See logcat below. Any help is really appreciated.

Here is how to reproduce the problem from scratch:

```
ionic start BLEscanner blank
cd BLEscanner/
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central --variable BLUETOOTH_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Scan for mesh packets"
npm install --save @ionic-native/ble
ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0 (tried with 7.1.0 and 6.4.0)
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

replace home.page.ts with this code:

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble/ngx';
import {
  Platform,
} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit  {
  constructor(
    private ble: BLE,
    private platform: Platform,
  ){
    console.log("constructor home page");
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    // Since ngOnInit() is executed before `deviceready` event,
    // you have to wait the event.
    await this.platform.ready();
    console.log(`enter view, start scanning`)
    this.ble.scan([], 5).subscribe(
      device =>
        console.log(JSON.stringify(device))),
      error => console.log(`error ${error}`);
  }
}
```

compile and run:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

check chrome://inspect/#devices for inspect and look at the console.
All you get is:

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
cordova.js:1218 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
vendor.js:74395 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 3303 ms
home-home-module.js:98 constructor home page
home-home-module.js:135 enter view, start scanning
```

There are no scanning results. Yes, there are many BLE advertisers present. And yes, the app has location privileges.

The error message in android logcat is:

```
05-03 15:30:42.368 17937 20508 I Places : ?: PlacesBleScanner stop()
05-03 15:30:42.394 17937 17937 I BeaconBle: 'L' hardware scan: scan stopped, no clients
05-03 15:30:42.394 17937 17937 I BeaconBle: Scan canceled successfully.
```

Any idea what's going on. Weird thing, this worked before. Some version mismatch?

Comment: the code you posted has no relation with the error message PlacesBleScanner, maybe you need to post here some extra classes.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: ionic version mismatch.
If @ionic-native/core and @ionic-native/ble are different, it stops working

This worked:

```
"@ionic-native/ble": "^5.5.1",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.5.1",
```